# VBA - Automation Error Exception Occurred

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

VBA generates 'Automation Error. Exception Occurred'.
Below mentioned procedure test1 crashes Excel for a specific group of users when .open method is called on Excel 2010, while other group of user are able to execute this successfully. Same users were able to execute this functions two weeks ago and suddenly one day it started throwing errors.
Below mentioned procedure test with ADO 2.7, 2.8, and 6.1 library but to no avail.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = OpenConnection(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    MsgBox conn.State = adStateOpen
End Sub
Public Function OpenConnection(ByVal sDB_Path As String) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sDB_Path & "; " & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
    Set OpenConnection = conn
End Function
```

Comment: are you sure sDB_Path is valid for those users? If the network drive is mapped to a different letter it would give that error

Comment: yes, this is completely fine. Few days back users were able to use this using same path.